# I don't know why there's spacing between my divs

Tags: css

I'm doing a footer with 4 different columns (divs). Those 4 `divs` are all in one container. I set the width of these divs to 25%, so they should all fit in the same "line", but they don't. I added a different `background-color` to each of the `divs` to see where the extra space is coming from and I saw that there's a space between the `divs` that is not a margin nor padding.
I looked it up on Stackoverflow and I thought I found a solution, but setting the `font-size` to 0 for the parent element and then resetting the `font-size` for the child element doesn't work...

```css
footer {
background-color: #000;
color: #BFBFBF;
padding: 60px;
}

.footer-container {
    width: 85%;
    background-color: red;
}

.footer-col {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
}

.fc-1 {
    background-color: orange;
}

.fc-2 {
    background-color: green;
}

.fc-3 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.fc-4 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

footer a {
    color: #BFBFBF;
    transition: none;
    display: block;
}

footer a:hover {
    color: #BFBFBF;
}
```

```html
<footer>

    <div class="footer-container">

        <div class="footer-col fc-1">
            <a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a>
            <a href="#">Kinesiotape</a>
            <a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a>
            <a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-col fc-2">
            <a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a>
            <a href="#">Kinesiotape</a>
            <a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a>
            <a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-col fc-3">
            <a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a>
            <a href="#">Kinesiotape</a>
            <a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a>
            <a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-col fc-4">
            <a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a>
            <a href="#">Kinesiotape</a>
            <a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a>
            <a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: Remove the whitespace between `</div>` and `<div>`.

Comment: https://codepen.io/rooiboQuality/pen/BayxXXp This is the codepen I forgot to add it

Comment: You can also add `display: flex;` to `.footer-container` since flex ignores white-space between elements / text.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all whitespaces:

```css
footer {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #BFBFBF;
  padding: 60px;
}

.footer-container {
  width: 85%;
  background-color: red;
}

.footer-col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
}

.fc-1 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.fc-2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.fc-3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.fc-4 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

footer a {
  color: #BFBFBF;
  transition: none;
  display: block;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #BFBFBF;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-container">
    <div class="footer-col fc-1">
      <a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a>
      <a href="#">Kinesiotape</a>
      <a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a>
      <a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a>
    </div><div class="footer-col fc-2">
      <a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a>
      <a href="#">Kinesiotape</a>
      <a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a>
      <a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a>
    </div><div class="footer-col fc-3">
      <a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a>
      <a href="#">Kinesiotape</a>
      <a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a>
      <a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a>
    </div><div class="footer-col fc-4">
      <a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a>
      <a href="#">Kinesiotape</a>
      <a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a>
      <a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

[Flexbox is a useful technique to position elements](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) like this so I would recommend using `display: flex;` on your container to fix the issue, you could also remove all the white-space in your container which [will prevent the spacing from appearing](https://medium.com/@patrickbrosset/when-does-white-space-matter-in-html-b90e8a7cdd33):

```css
.footer-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 85%;
    background-color: red;
}

.footer-col {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
}

.fc-1 {
    background-color: orange;
}

.fc-2 {
    background-color: green;
}

.fc-3 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.fc-4 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

footer a {
    color: #BFBFBF;
    transition: none;
    display: block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

footer a:hover {
    color: #BFBFBF;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <div class="footer-container">
        <div class="footer-col fc-1">
            <a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a>
            <a href="#">Kinesiotape</a>
            <a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a>
            <a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-col fc-2">
            <a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a>
            <a href="#">Kinesiotape</a>
            <a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a>
            <a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-col fc-3">
            <a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a>
            <a href="#">Kinesiotape</a>
            <a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a>
            <a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-col fc-4">
            <a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a>
            <a href="#">Kinesiotape</a>
            <a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a>
            <a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `flex-box` you will bet able to fix this problem using `flex-basis: 25%;
flex-grow: 0;` instead of `width: 25%;`

```css
footer {
background-color: #000;
color: #BFBFBF;
padding: 60px;
}

.footer-container {
    width: 85%;
    display: flex;
    background-color: red;
}

.footer-col {
    display: inline-block;
    flex-basis: 25%;
flex-grow: 0;
}

.fc-1 {
    background-color: orange;
}

.fc-2 {
    background-color: green;
}

.fc-3 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.fc-4 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

footer a {
    color: #BFBFBF;
    transition: none;
    display: block;
}

footer a:hover {
    color: #BFBFBF;
}
```

```html
<footer>

    <div class="footer-container">

        <div class="footer-col fc-1">
            <a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a>
            <a href="#">Kinesiotape</a>
            <a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a>
            <a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-col fc-2">
            <a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a>
            <a href="#">Kinesiotape</a>
            <a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a>
            <a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-col fc-3">
            <a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a>
            <a href="#">Kinesiotape</a>
            <a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a>
            <a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-col fc-4">
            <a href="#">Ledmanipulation</a>
            <a href="#">Kinesiotape</a>
            <a href="#">Akut skadesbehandling</a>
            <a href="#">Triggerpunktsbehandling</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: @RooiboQuallity Not a problem ;) Please `accept` my answer and `upvote` it if it helped you :)